# How to use predict.stepplr() and confusionmatrix() correctly for step.plr method?

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, predict, confusion-matrix

```
#Here is my code:
library(MASS, caret, stepPlr, janitor)
#stepPlr: L2 penalized logistic regression with a stepwise variable selection
#MASS: Support Functions and Datasets for Venables and Ripley's MASS
#caret: Classification and Regression Training
#janitor: Simple Tools for Examining and Cleaning Dirty Data

#Howells is a main dataframe, we will segregate it.
HNORSE <- Howells[which(Pop=='NORSE'),]
#Let's remove NA cols 
#We will use janitor package here to remove NA cols

HNORSE <- remove_empty_cols(HNORSE)
#Assigning 0's and 1's to females and males resp.
HNORSE$PopSex[HNORSE$PopSex=="NORSEF"] <- '0'
HNORSE$PopSex[HNORSE$PopSex=="NORSEM"] <- '1'

HNORSE$PopSex <- as.numeric(HNORSE$PopSex)
HNORSE$PopSex
#Resultant column looks like this
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
    1 1 1 1 1
[41] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
    0 0 0 0 0 0
[81] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I want to use Stepplr from caret package

```
a <- step.plr(HNORSE[,c(6:76)], HNORSE$PopSex, lambda = 1e-4, cp="bic",    max.terms = 1, trace = TRUE, type = "forward")

#Where HNORSE[,c(6:76)] --> features 
#HNORSE$PopSex ---> Binary response
#lambda ----> Default value 
#max.terms ---> I tried more than 1 value for max.terms, but then R goes into infinite loop of 'Convergence Error'. 
#That's why using max.terms=1
```

Then I ran summary command on "a"

```
summary(a)
Call: plr(x = ix0, y = y, weights = weights, offset.subset = offset.subset, 
offset.coefficients = offset.coefficients, lambda = lambda, 
cp = cp)

Coefficients:Estimate Std.Error z value Pr(>|z|)
Intercept -71.93470   13.3521  -5.388        0
ZYB         0.55594    0.1033   5.382        0

    Null deviance: 152.49 on 109 degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 57.29 on 108 degrees of freedom
            Score: deviance + 4.7 * df = 66.69
```

I used step.plr so, I should then use predict.stepplr right? and not predict.plr?

By this logic I wish to use predict.stepplr. *The default function argument example goes like this:*

```
n <- 100
p <- 5
x0 <- matrix(sample(seq(3),n*p,replace=TRUE),nrow=n) 
x0 <- cbind(rnorm(n),x0)
y <- sample(c(0,1),n,replace=TRUE)
level <- vector("list",length=6)
for (i in 2:6) level[[i]] <- seq(3)
fit <- step.plr(x0,y,level=level)
x1 <- matrix(sample(seq(3),n*p,replace=TRUE),nrow=n)
x1 <- cbind(rnorm(n),x1)
pred1 <- predict(fit,x0,x1,type="link")
pred2 <- predict(fit,x0,x1,type="response")
pred3 <- predict(fit,x0,x1,type="class")


object:    stepplr object
x:         matrix of features used for fitting object. 
If newx is provided, x must be provided as well.
newx:     matrix of features at which the predictions are made. 

If newx=NULL, predictions for the training data are returned.
type:      If type=link, the linear predictors are returned; 

if type=response, the probability estimates are returned; and
if type=class, the class labels are returned. Default is type=link.
... 
other options for prediction..
```

- So First of all, I did not do any sampling like shown in here.
- I want to predict **HNORSE$PopSex** which is binary variable.
- My dataset which **does not include the binary variable column is HNORSE[,c(6:76)]**.
- I want to know what **x0** and **x1** function arguments should I put in
  **predict.stepplr()**?
- If not, **HOW** do I correctly implement
  predict.stepplr?
- I want to use overall accuracy to plot(Density(overall_accuracy))